# Conekta And ReactJS Implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, payment

I want to implement Conekta payment service with Reactjs and Node as backend.
Currently, i am not able to set some configurations, I found in another question the following helper, and that's the one that I am currently using.

```
import config from './config'

const conektaHelper = {
  initConekta: () => {
    window.Conekta.setPublicKey(config.conekta.staging.publicKey)
  },
  getCardBrand: (cardNumber) => {
    return window.Conekta.card.getBrand(cardNumber)
  },
  validateCardNumber: (cardNumber) => {
    return window.Conekta.card.validateNumber(cardNumber)
  },
  validateCvc: (cvc) => {
    return window.Conekta.card.validateCVC(cvc)
  },
  validateExpirationDate: (expiryMonth, expiryYear) => {
    return window.Conekta.card.validateExpirationDate(expiryMonth, `20${expiryYear}`)
  },
  tokenize: (cardNumber, cardHolder, expiryMonth, expiryYear, cvc, successCallback, errorCallback) => {
    const tokenParams = {
      card: {
        number: cardNumber,
        name: cardHolder,
        exp_year: expiryYear,
        exp_month: expiryMonth,
        cvc
      }
    }
    window.Conekta.Token.create(tokenParams, successCallback, errorCallback)
  }
}

export default conektaHelper
```

I am using this useEffect as well on the App.js file

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://cdn.conekta.io/js/latest/conekta.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, []);
```

Basically, it adds the conekta cdn to ReactJs.

I am having issues with this implementation, because I don't understand how to implement that very well.

Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEfbZ.png)